# Fail while unwrapping data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project and I need to fetch the data of imaginary restaurants from my realtime database. I have added a print statement to my code and it always says that: "Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key". This is my function for displaying the restaurants:

```swift
func fetchRestaurantData(completion: @escaping ([Restaurants]?) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("restaurants")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot, _) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                var restaurants: [Restaurants] = []
                for (key, restaurantInfo) in data {
                    if let restaurantData = restaurantInfo as? [String: Any] {
                        if let address = restaurantData["address"] as? String,
                           let category = restaurantData["category"] as? String,
                           let name = restaurantData["name"] as? String,
                           let rating = restaurantData["rating"] as? String,
                           let status = restaurantData["status"] as? String {
                            let restaurant = Restaurants(name: name, rating: rating, address: address, category: category, status: status)
                            restaurants.append(restaurant)
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: \(key)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                completion(restaurants)
            } else {
                print("No valid data found in snapshot")
                completion(nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("No data found in the snapshot")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The data in the firebase is stored in this way:

[image: Firebase data structure]

I want to display them in my collectionView, but as I said before, it prints "Failed to unwrap ..."

Comment: can you show us the `exact` print you get?

Comment: I'm getting the fail for all my categories. Here is the print statement result:

Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: italian;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: indian;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: american;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: french;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: mexican;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: japanese;
Failed to unwrap values for restaurant with key: chinese;

Comment: just guessing maybe you are getting an array of dictionaries, `[[String: Any]]`

Comment: Did not work unfortunately :(

Comment: in your Firebase, there's a node "american" between "restaurants" and the restaurant array.

Comment: I got 9 category nodes as "american","chinese", "japanese" etc. in my restaurants. Do I need to consider it while unwrapping value. If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As soundfix commented, there are two dynamic levels under `restaurants` before we get to the properties of an actual restaurant:

1. There's `american`, probably something about the cuisine.
2. There's the `-N...` value, a so-called push key usually generated by calling Firebase's `childByAutoId` or `push` method.

Your code handles only one of these dynamic levels (with `for (key, restaurantInfo) in data {`), but you need such a loop for **both** of them.

So something like:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot, _) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for cuisineSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            for restaurantSnapshot in cuisineSnapshot.children {
                if let restaurantData = restaurantSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                    ...
```

You'll note that I loop over the child nodes through the `children` property as also shown in the Firebase documentation on [listening for lists of children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).